# is.na() counts a valid date as NA

Tags: r

I created a datetime column from a character column like this:

```
dat$created_datetime <- strptime(dat$created_at, format = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
```

My cleanup code is reporting NAs in this column, but the entries look fine:

```
> dat$created_datetime[514]
[1] "2016-10-02 02:26:00"
> is.na(dat$created_datetime[514])
[1] TRUE
> str(dat$created_datetime)
POSIXlt[1:300400], format: "2016-06-29 13:10:00" "2016-06-30 03:56:00" "2016-07-05 09:43:00" "2016-07-12 06:47:00" "2016-07-13 06:57:00" "2016-07-13 10:11:00" ...
```

Only 62 of 300k rows are affected. I can't figure out what's going on.

Comment: Would help to see `dat$created_at[514]`.

Comment: `dat$created_datetime[514]` cannot be both `2016-10-02 02:26:00` and `NA`. There is some mistake here, but currently not enough information to solve it.

Comment: Are you in Australia? https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/australia/canberra?year=2016

Comment: `is.na.POSIXlt` applies `as.POSIXct` internally. That potentially changes  the timezone to your system timezone if it was a different timezone before. I suggest to make the datetimes POSIXct yourself and ensure that you set a timezone without DST such as `tz = "GMT"`. There is no reason to use POSIXlt. You should also always set the timezone manually when you parse datetimes.

Answer (score 1):

You are incorrectly specifying the parameters of your date.  For example you have the day first - when the string you gave starts with a year.    Consult https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/dates.html - for examples of what %d , %H ,etc, stand for. Also note, that the string you gave is separated by "-" not by "/"  Check out my code - I took your data and am able to get it to load correctly.  The first chunk is what you are doing - the second is corrected

```
a <- "2016-10-02 02:26:00"
a <- strptime(a, format = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
is.na( a )

a <- "2016-10-02 02:26:00"
a <-  as.POSIXct(a, format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
is.na( a )
```

Comment: Not sure that this is the issue. The input to `strptime` is `dat$created_at`, the format of which is not shown in the question, not `dat$created_datetime` which is the output.